# Problem with create androidapps using Firebase Management Api

Tags: android, firebase, google-apis-explorer

I have read these documents about create android apps using firebase management api.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps/create
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps#AndroidApp

Document doesn't mention which field is required to create app.

After calling below request:

```
POST v1beta1/projects/sublime-formula-310010/androidApps
{
  "displayName": "ggds",
  "packageName": "sdf.aw.dsff",
  "projectId": "sublime-formula-310010",
  "appId": "asdfasdfaewrwe",
  "name": "projects/sublime-formula-310010/androidApps/asdfasdfaewrwe"
}
```

I get below error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
{
  "displayName": "alline",
   "packageName": "com.alline.app"
}
```